# Boostrap navbar form and links using navbar-right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to use navbar-right on a navbar-form and a navbar-nav however it ends up putting the form on one row and the navbar_nav on another row on the right. How can I get the navbar to show the brand on the left and on the right is a search field followed by a nav links.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid col-sm-12 col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                  data-target="#navbar_collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/" style="white-space:nowrap">Site</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar_collapse">
          <div class="navbar-right">
            <form class="navbar-form" role="search" ng-submit="collectionSearch()">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Collection ID"
                       ng-model="cSearch" size=10 required>
              </div>
            </form>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li id="create_tab"><a href="/">Create</a></li>
              <li id="tests_tab"><a href="#/tests">Tests</a></li>
              <li id="collections_tab"><a href="#/collections">Collections</a></li>
              <li id="account_tab"><a href="#/account">Account</a></li>
              <li id="logout_tab" ><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: you want like this? http://jsbin.com/larecapotuvi/1

Comment: @KheemaPandey Close, except that I need the form to be on the left of the links instead of on the right.

Comment: check now the link? http://jsbin.com/larecapotuvi/1 works for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this bootstrap classes `navbar-form` and `navbar-left` to move the search icon on left side. Here is a [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/larecapotuvi/1).

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" ng-submit="collectionSearch()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this should answer your question:

http://jsfiddle.net/zu5uoopc/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However the order gets reversed when you do it this way. I would like the form to be on the left of the links when the bar is not collapsed and at the top when it is collapsed. But here the form is at the bottom when collapsed. Do you know how I could do this?